# How to get an uploaded file URL from the shopify Admin API

Tags: php, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am currently saving some images in shopify via File API:

```
mutation fileCreate($files: [FileCreateInput!]!) {
                fileCreate(files: $files) {
                files {
                    alt
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
                }
            }',
        [
            'files' => [
                'alt' => $alt_text,
                'contentType' => 'IMAGE',
                'originalSource' => $from_url,
            ]
        ]
```

It works, but unfortunately I am not able to get the url in return. It returns null as if it's still processing.
Is there any way to do it? I am saving the image name locally, but I wouldn't consider querying the api again for each single one a valid solution (too many files, huge overhead)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @NemoPS, Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue so you may be able to help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above code on my project and it works but i didn't get any return url but get the following response object.

```
[
   {
     alt: 'pexels-albina-white-11780519.jpg',
     createdAt: '2022-07-12T06:07:59Z',
     fileErrors: [],
     fileStatus: 'UPLOADED',
     __typename: 'GenericFile',
     preview: { image: null }
   }
 ]
```

Shopify didn't provide the reading files from admin file not from any api for public apps.If any idea to read file from the api admin file then Please answer for this Query.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32226476)